# iOS page with scrollView randomly not loading contentView correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode9.2

I have a page that has been working fine prior to Xcode 9.2.  After updating to 9.2 the page will randomly not load correctly.  See images below.  The one on the left is how the page should look, but sometimes I get the page on the right.

[Image of what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maK1S.png)

My contentView is wrapped inside of a scrollView, and all the pinning and aligning has been set.  There are no layout issues/warnings from the storyboard (like I said this had been working without issue for at least 2 versions of Xcode now).
It happens on a per build bases meaning that it is either correct for a build or not.  What's worse is that I can go in and edit a completely different view controller, build and get this to happen or correct itself.  Also when I get the bad load on the simulator, I can take that same build put it on my device and the page loads fine.

I tried removing my contentView from the scrollView and that seems to always load correctly, but then I have to take care of scrolling the view when the keyboard is displayed (the whole reason I wrapped the contentView within a scrollView to begin with).  I know it's long shot, but I'm wondering if anyone has experienced anything like this.  I know I could try using a tableView instead of a scrollView, but I'd really like to avoid re-writing something that has been working fine.

Comment: If it's any consolation, I've also been seeing this issue. Came out of nowhere for me, too.

Comment: Maybe you could provide some code/xib

Comment: need to know the constraints given within your containerView and scrollView to answer this

Answer (score 0):

As I was trying to pull together code to share, I noticed that my contentView (that was inside my scrollView) somehow had a referencing outlet set to my viewController. Upon removing this referencing outlet I haven't been able to recreate the issue.